# hdd goes to sleep only when in hotplug

Tags: hard-drive, noise, hotplug

i have absolutely quiet computer while in idle mode. Only 1 thing is making noise - that is hdd that I use very rarely, so it always keeps spinning though I'm not using it.
In fact I have a case with hot-plug for hdd and when I plug it in there it stops spinning after about 1 minute (sleep mode for hdd after 1 min in windows enabled).  How can I make it do the same thing while hdd is internal? (hotplug mode is enabled for all satas in bios). I'm running under Windows 7  64-bit. Thank you.

Comment: I think word 5, "comp", means computer. You have a much better chance of getting an answer if you show a bit more energy and write out what you actually mean.

Comment: sorry for my english, that is not my native language

Comment: Do the changes I've made make sense?

Comment: It would help if you [edit[ the question to include your operating system ...

Comment: Xavierjazz, you forgot dot after "Thank you".

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved after I plugged in my hdd to a sata port on motherboard where hot-plug module was plugged in, seems strange to me.